# Passbook passes can not be removed by app

Tags: ios, passbook

I've implemented Passbook in the normal way and it worked during development and testing perfectly. But the app available at the AppStore can only create and add a pass, but not removing a previously created one.

Here is a little overview of what worked at which stage of development:

```
                  Simulator     Ad-Hoc Build     AppStore-Build
Creation of Pass       X              X                  X 
Updating               X              X                  X      
Removing               X              X                  -
```

That means creating, updating and deleting a pass works in every step, but at the final AppStore-Build I cannot delete a pass.

I've figured out that the request [PKPassLibrary passWithPassTypeIdentifier:serialnumber:] returns nil before trying to remove a pass. But it the same method returns a valid pass while trying to update a pass.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you've added the passbook capability to your app and you've added passbook to the app id in the dev portal? I found the same thing until I added the capabilities. Now it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot remove a Pass from Passbook with your App. After a user has added a Pass to Passbook, it is no longer 'yours'. You can send a push notification saying that a Pass is no longer valid - but you cannot delete it remotely or via an App.

Comment: and why is there a corresponding method: [PKPassLibrary removePass:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPassLibrary_Ref/PKPassLibrary.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PKPassLibrary/removePass:)

Comment: Here's an excerpt from the Passbook Programming Guide: Removing a Pass

Use the removePass: method of the PKPassLibrary class to remove a pass.

Remember that passes belong to the user, not to your app. Pass removal should be done only in response to a direct user action. Never remove a pass without the user’s consent, even if the pass is expired or outdated.

Comment: Yes that means you as developer must ensure that no pass is removed without knowledge of the user. It means not that is not possible (if it should be not possible why not making the "removePass:" method private). In my case the user pressed a "Cancel reservation" button and the corresponding pass should be removed.